# Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit: "could not access network location %SystemRoot% /fonts

Tags: windows-7, windows

I recently purchased Serif WebPlus X5. When I tried to install it I get the following error message:

> Could not access network location %SystemRoot%/Fonts

I checked with the software manufacturer who said the software is compatible with Windows 7 64-bit.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Does it really use `/` instead of `\ `?

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with @Mehrdad, the issue is because the path should be %systemroot%\Fonts

Confirm that is the case, then contact the program vendor for technical support.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure the install is running as administrator?

It is also possible that the program, (either from an error/limitation or configuration error) is looking for an actual folder called %SystemRoot%, rather than expanding that to the location where windows is installed. Since I don't know anything about how they determine the folder, I can only guess and my best guess you be that it is looking in the registry for the value against key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Fonts
```

Mine says REG_SZ C:\Windows\Fonts.

What does your say?

The actual / vs \ is probably a red-herring as the operating system should be able to cope with either.